# Deriving the particle filter with driving-force/inputs/control-signal

Tags: inference, state-space-models, particle-filter, approximate-inference, control-theory

[image]

Whenever the particle filter is derived (I used a different condition for $u_t$ as a solution to the nonlinear filtering problem;

$x_{t+1} \mid x_t \sim f_{\theta}(x_{t+1} \mid x_t,u_t) \\ 
y_{t} \mid x_t \sim g_{\theta}(y_{t} \mid x_t,u_t) \\
\theta \sim \mathbb{P}(\theta) \text{ - Just some initial parameter density}$

typically it is common to "(without loss of generality) drop the known input $u_t$ from the notation". Or [as this paper says](http://www.dsi.unifi.it/users/chisci/idfric/Nonlinear_filtering_Chen.pdf):

> For discussion simplicity, no driving-force in the dynamic system
>   (which is often referred to the stochastic control problem) is considered
>   in this paper. However, the extension to the driven system is
>   straightforward.

Now I happen to be interested in the stochastic control problem, and I am basically wondering if my derivation is correct when one does chose to include $u_t$. I am somewhat worried that it is not as plug and play as the authors claim.

For the filtering problem, the recursion equations are (see eq 1 of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter)):

$p_{\theta}(x_t \mid y_{1:t}) = \frac{g_{\theta} (y_t \mid x_t) p_{\theta}(x_t \mid y_{1:t-1})}{p_{\theta}(y_t \mid y_{1:t-1})} \\
p_{\theta}(x_t \mid y_{1:t-1}) = \int f_{\theta} (x_t \mid x_{t-1})p_{\theta}(x_{t-1} \mid y_{1:t-1})dx_{t-1}$

and what we are interested in are the relations for $p_{\theta}(x_t \mid y_{1:t},u_{1:t})$.

Here is an attempt (I'll drop $\theta$ for now).

$p(x_t \mid y_{1:t},u_{1:t}) = \frac{p(x_{t},u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t})p(y_{1:t})}{p(u_{1:t},y_{1:t})} \\$
which we can simplify to

$p(x_t \mid y_{1:t},u_{1:t}) = \frac{p(x_{t},u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t})p(y_{1:t})}{p(y_{1:t})p(u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t})}\\
p(x_t \mid y_{1:t},u_{1:t}) = \frac{p(x_{t},u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t})}{p(u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t})}\\$

But then this seems wrong, and I we would have to approximate then some integral:

$p(x_{t},u_{1:t} \mid y_{1:t}) = \int ...? \ \ d? d?$

This is probably very trivial but has left me confused.